# Parse PFUser currentUser query key

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to match a value under a certain key to the [PFUser currentUser] value.  However, when I log this out I notice it lists all of the PFUser attributes.  If there a certain way to see if a value matches the [PFUser currentUser]?

```
PFQuery *queryForMatchedLikes = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[firstToUserQuery, secondToUserQuery]];
[queryForMatchedLikes findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.matches = [objects mutableCopy];   
        if ([self.matches count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"No matches yet");
        } else {
            for (PFObject *match in self.matches) {
                if (match[kDDActivityFirstToUserKey] == [PFUser currentUser]) {
                    NSLog(@"first event");
                } else if (match[kDDActivitySecondToUserKey] == [PFUser currentUser]) {
                    NSLog(@"second event");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by finding the objectId 's of both values.

```
PFQuery *queryForMatchedLikes = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[firstToUserQuery, secondToUserQuery]];
[queryForMatchedLikes findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.matches = [objects mutableCopy];   
        if ([self.matches count] == 0) {
            NSLog(@"No matches yet");
        } else {
            for (PFObject *match in self.matches) {
                if ([[match[kDDActivityFirstToUserKey] objectId] isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
                    NSLog(@"first event");
                } else if ([[match[kDDActivitySecondToUserKey] objectId] isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
                    NSLog(@"second event");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}];
```